# Exchange limited validity Australian license for UK license

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, driving-license

My Australian driving license is valid until April 2019. I have been resident in the UK since Sept 2017. I would like to exchange my Australian DL for a UK DL. Would the fact that my Australian driving license is about to expire mean that I'll get a UK drivers' license with limited validity?
That is, is the validity of the exchanged license tied with the license of my current driving license.

Comment: If you’ve continued to drive since becoming a resident, you should have exchanged it by September 2018 https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence/y/yes/car-or-motorcycle/a-designated-country-countries-with-exchange-agreements-with-great-britain/australia

Comment: I understand that. However, I have not been driving since then and would like to drive now. Hence the question.

Comment: The website states that I can exchange my license up to 5 years after becoming a resident.

Comment: @SangeetaBhatia Yes, you are right! I indeed believe if you exchange it now, you'll get a 10 year licence.